# How to match data in two different column in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables, in one table, the columns are 
operations & grp
e.g;

```
operation     grp
created       login
sign in       login
```

In another table, B column are;

```
uid       operation 
1         created
2         sign in
```

I want to match each data from both tables and would like the output as follows;

```
uid       grp
1         login
2         login
```

How could I do this in `SQL`???

Answer (score 1):

Try to join both table using [`INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). Since the column `operation` is common in both tables, you can join using `operation`.

```
SELECT B.uid, A.grp 
FROM A JOIN B ON A.operation = B.operation
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1167a/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
select B.uid,A.grp from tableA  A join tableB B on A.operation=B.operation
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select uid, grp from table1, table2 where table1.operation = table2.operation
```